# Claws mail does not minimise to notification/indicator applet

Tags: 16.04, indicator, notification, claws

I am using `Claws Mail v3.13.2` on `Ubuntu 16.04`. Before upgrading to 16.04 from 15.10 the claws mail plugin `Notification` managed to minimise and/or close claws mail to tray (i.e., in this little mail symbol in the top right corner - the notification/indicator applet).

However, this does not work anymore under 16.04.

When I minimise claws mail it gets minimised as every other program into launcher panel. When I close claws mail it just terminates the program.

**So how do I get claws mail to minimise/close to tray again?**

Ps.: `Liferae` closes/minimises to tray as expected and can be re-opened by clicking on the mail symbol in the top right corner.

PPs.: Under 15.10 the indicator applet even allowed me to receive new mails and open a new (composing) mail window. So it seems that the integration of claws mail under 15.10 worked well but was somehow 'removed' or damaged in 16.04.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved in 16.04?  I've been having the same issue and cannot get a response from claws mail forum on this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I also sent a mail to the claws mails development team. Never got a reply.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Claws-mail tray notifier: sudo apt install claws-mail-multi-notifier
2. Load the plugin from Claws Mail: Configuration -> Plugins
3. Configure the plugin from Claws Mail: Configuration -> Preferences
4. Now Add or Edit a file named claws-mail.desktop in startup directory having following content:-

> Content of:  ~/.config/autostart/claws-mail.desktop

`[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Claws Mail
GenericName=E-mail client
Exec=sh -c "sleep 10 && claws-mail &"
Icon=claws-mail
Categories=Network;Email;
Keywords=lightweight;fast;gui;extensible;plugin;pop;pop3;imap;imap4;nntp;news;
Comment=Lightweight and Fast GTK+ based Mail Client
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
X-Info=Claws Mail`